# filtering depth first search output

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

i want to try filter my ouput in depth first search.
output from this code are **0 1 2 5 6**. i want to filter it so i can make solution for shortest path that finish to 6 to **0 2 6** is there some way to do it?

code goes like this :

```
public class DFS {

private int V; 
private LinkedList<Integer> adj[];

DFS(int v)
{
    V = v;
    adj = new LinkedList[v];
    for (int i=0; i<v; ++i)
        adj[i] = new LinkedList();
}

void addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].add(w);  }

void DFSUtil(int v,boolean visited[])
{
    visited[v] = true;
           System.out.print(v+ " ");        
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[v].listIterator();                   
                while (i.hasNext())
                {
                        int n = i.next();                             
                        if (!visited[n])
                                DFSUtil(n, visited);

                        if(visited[6] == true)
                            break;
                }                                                                             


}

void dfs(int v)
{       
    boolean visited[] = new boolean[V];
    DFSUtil(v, visited);    }
```

here is the edge :

g.addEdge(0, 1);

g.addEdge(0, 2);

g.addEdge(0, 3);

g.addEdge(0, 4);

g.addEdge(2, 5);

g.addEdge(2, 6);

g.addEdge(3, 7);

g.addEdge(3, 8);

g.addEdge(3, 4);

g.addEdge(8, 9);

g.addEdge(8, 3);

g.addEdge(9, 8);

g.addEdge(9, 10);

g.addEdge(10, 9);

g.addEdge(10, 4);

g.addEdge(4, 0);

g.addEdge(4, 3);

g.addEdge(4, 6);

g.addEdge(4, 10);

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
 // i put addEdge in here 
 g.dfs(0);}
```